# Limits for JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing

I´m using an application with a dialog box derived from JFileChooser.
My costumer writes data in a folder where one file is generated at each hour, and the filename shows when (ex: 20180830_1600.txt).

Then he sent me a screen where the file list, in chronological order, didn´t show most of these archives (For example: I see today´s 20180830_1100.txt and 20180830_1600.txt, but I don´t see the files from 20180830_1200.txt to 20180830_1500.txt).

I imagine that this problem is caused for having too much files on this folder. He´s been saving files for more than a year, and he has more than 10,000 files.

So, my question: is there some limit for a JFileChooser object (such as maximum number of files / maximum size in bytes) ?
Or can this be caused for exceeding some memory limit for the Java application ?

Thanks !

Comment: The file chooser only displays the file name so the file size would be irrelevant. Did you verify if the files actually exist In the directory using the file browser of the OS? Don't know if there is a limit or not but I would suggest you should have a better API to look at the files. Maybe save files in directories by year or month. Then have an interface where the user selects the year/month to get a list of files. You can even provide a time range. It makes no sense to scroll through 10K files in the chooser to find the file you want.

Comment: When I wrote "size", this was not about the file size, of course, but the amount of bytes needed to store the file names. Each filename has 25 bytes (more than the 17 byes in my example above - 18 if terminator needed). If I have 10,000 files, this means I need 250k only for these filenames. How are these controls, such as file lists, designed ? Can they handle as many items I insert into them ? Or do they have a limit ?

Comment: Yes, the files really exist. The user who pointed to this question sent me a screen with a part of the file listing of the directory and a part of the file list shown by the control.

Comment: How this problem of storing files can be handled is another question we may consider later. By now, our problem is related to the memory use by a JFileChooser object. I´d like to have some information about it. As far I have seen in the documentation of JFileChooser class, there´s no specification about memory limit. But how does it work ? Can it dinamically increase its memory space, accepting any amount of items while they are inserted ?

Comment: A JFileChooser is basically just a JList  and a few other buttons to help you select a file from the list. A JList uses a ListModel to store the data. There is no limitation  other than you must be able to access an item in the model using an int value, so it can support well over 10k items. Try a simple test yourself. Try loading the filenames into a JList and see if you have any problems. If there is a memory limitation it is for the JVM, not the file chooser. You should get messages if you are out of memory. I believe you can specify the stack/heap size, but I don't know how.

Comment: Thanks, camickr ! That´s the answer I needed. With my working machine, I´m not getting problems with memory, just in our customer´s machine, and I can´t do this test there.